# How to add textbox values to list using MVVM?

Tags: c#, wpf, mvvm, data-binding

Models

```
public class EmployeeDetails
{
    public string Name { get; set; } 
    public int Age {get;set;}
} 

public class AddressDetails
{
    public EmployeeDetails EmployeeName { get; set; }
    public string City { get; set; }
}
```

View

```
<Window x:Class="ClassCollection.MainWindow"
    xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
    xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
    xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008"
    xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006"
    xmlns:local="clr-namespace:ClassCollection"
    mc:Ignorable="d"
    Title="MainWindow" Height="350" Width="525"
    DataContext="{Binding Source={StaticResource loc},Path=ViewModel}"
    >
<Grid>
    <StackPanel Margin="0 20 0 0">
        <TextBox x:Name="txt1" Width="90" Height="20" Text="{Binding Details.EmployeeName}"/>
        <TextBox x:Name="txt2" Width="90" Height="20" Text="{Binding Details.City}"  Margin="0 20 0 0"/>
    </StackPanel>
    <Button x:Name="btn" Width="90" Height="25" Content="Add" Command="  {Binding AddCommand}"/>
</Grid>
</Window>
```

ViewModel

```
public class Viewmodel
{
    public ObservableCollection<AddressDetails> EmployeeList;
    public Viewmodel()
    {
        EmployeeList = new ObservableCollection<AddressDetails>();
        LoadCommand();
    }

    private AddressDetails _details;
    public AddressDetails Details
    {
        get { return _details; }
        set
        {
            _details = value;
        }
    }

    // Commands
    public ICommand AddCommand { get; set; }

    private void LoadCommand()
    {
        AddCommand = new CustomCommand(Add, CanAdd);
    }

    private bool CanAdd(object obj)
    {
        return true;
    }

    private void Add(object obj)
    {
        EmployeeList.Add(new AddressDetails { EmployeeName = Details.EmployeeName, City = Details.City });
    }
}
```

Locator

```
public class Locator
{
    private static Viewmodel viewmodel = new Viewmodel();
    public static Viewmodel ViewModel
    {
        get { return viewmodel; }
    }
}
```

How to add `TextBox` value to collection list using MVVM?

The Above is my code that I have tried. It shows null reference exception if I do like above. What would be the problem?

## Update

I have two fields in `EmployeeDetails` class. So I must give input for these two field when add to collection. But I need only one field `Name` to insert to the collection. How to do it?

Comment: Use the Debugger, step through your code. Then you can see which specific line throws the NullReferenceException. As for your code, are you implementing INotifyPropertyChanged anywhere? Otherwise, your View won't be notified of changes to the Observable Collection.

Comment: It seems instead of the `Text="{Binding Details.EmployeeName}"` binding  the `Text="{Binding Details.EmployeeName.Name}"` binding should be used.

Comment: Could you please post the appropriate code or pseudocode to illustrate this: «So I must give input for these two field when add to collection. But I need only one field Name to insert to the collection.»?

Answer (score 1):

## Analysis

It seems the `_details` field is not «initialized».

## Solution

Please consider introducing the appropriate field initialization, for example:

```
private readonly AddressDetails _details = new AddressDetails
    {
        EmployeeName = new EmployeeDetails()
    };
```

Comment: Works Well.. Thanks @Sergey Brunov

Comment: One more doubt. if i have one more field(Name,Age) in the EmployeeDetails class and  need only one field(Name) in AddressDetails class then we can use contructor right?? if yes then how to initialize that  _details property??

Comment: @A.Manikandan, glad it helped! Sorry, I didn't understand the question. Could you please update the current question or ask it as a separate question?

Comment: @A.Manikandan, let's continue the question clarification in the comments section of the question.